# PHP regex to avoid inserting digits in field while working with Unicode

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I have a form in my application that will fill using Unicode characters (Non English). As name field needs to fill just with letters, I have to detect numbers as an error. On the other hand, I don't know how can I write the exact regular expression that works on Unicode.
Please help me.

Comment: `\d` will match numbers just fine. Have you tried using it to detect invalid input?

Comment: I'm a bit weak in regex @Jon, could you show me a sample code ? Be aware that I don't like to remove digits myself. I have to detect it only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_match ('/\d/u', $string)` will do.

The *u* modifier makes it safe to use on unicode strings

Comment: yup but doesn't restrict it to characters as asked for.

Comment: He just wants to find if there are numbers inside a unicode string. What's missing?

Comment: @Brian absolutely your code is more complete. But what Edson said is correct too for me and helped me. I thank you from both of you.

Comment: OK but it does'nt 'detect numbers as an error' as you're original request asked for.

Answer (score 2):

I got this from a previous answer... but forget which one - its now in my snippet library...

```
$post = '9999, škofja loka';
echo preg_match('/^\\d{4},[\\s\\p{L}]+$/u', $post);
```